# Excel to append cell contents to the end of text files. How?

Tags: excel, append, vba

I have an excel file with file names in A column and line contents in column B.

It looks like this:

```
file1|content1
file2|content2
file3|content3
```

I also have a macro VBA script that creates txt files on disk with file name from column A and with contents from column B.
Here's the script:

```
Sub Export_Files()
Dim sExportFolder, sFN
Dim rArticleName As Range
Dim rDisclaimer As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oFS As Object
Dim oTxt As Object

'sExportFolder = path to the folder you want to export to
'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
sExportFolder = "C:\path\to\folder"
Set oSh = Sheet1

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    Set rDisclaimer = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)

    'Add .txt to the article name as a file name
    sFN = rArticleName.Value & ".txt"
    Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
    oTxt.Write rDisclaimer.Value
    oTxt.Close
Next
End Sub
```

It works like it should, however now I would like to append some other data to the end of the existing files from the excel sheet and current script overwrites the files and they contain only one line of data in them, the one that appears last in the excel for the given file name.

It would look look like this:

```
file1|content1
file2|content2
file3|content3
file1|new_content4
file2|new_content5
file3|new_content6
```

So the file1.txt would have two lines now, as an example:

```
content1
new_content4
```

Is it possible to have data from column B appended to the ends of file names with names on column A? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `iomode` parameter of `OpenTextFile` to `ForAppending`, or 8:

```
Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(sExportFolder & "\" & sFN, 8, True)
```

You may need to add a `WriteLine` call if you wish append on a new line in the file.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx